# Documentum DQL Editor?

Tags: documentum, documentum-dql

I am using Documentum which is on the remote server.I want to see the data in dm_sysobject table.Through my research I found that we can see the table data in DQL Editor.But,I am unable to find from where can I get this DQL Editor.Do I need to install this separately?.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

If you use Documentum Administrator go to Tools -> DQL Editor. 
If you want to use standalone application you can use DQMan or Repoint.

Comment: Thanks miki.Do I need to Install DQMan or Repoint?.If Yes,It would be really helpful if you can provide me some references from where I can install DQMan or Repoint

Comment: comon, why don't you try googling? The first result gives the link to download: https://www.fme-us.com/pro/our-products-2/dqman/free-download

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing a 3rd party DQL Editor, you might want to use idql/idql32 as built-in DQL Editor.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can download free java based small dql editor tool from 
http://www.icontentxlabs.com/ which can dump on right click , export to excel,
no installation needed just copy paste